# hashlib.md5(b"").digest() equivalente no PHP

Tags: php, python-3.x

Olá pessoal estou com o seguinte problema preciso criar um script php com base em um script python ia tudo bem até eu encontrar isso:

`hashlib.md5(b"55M5033B556EUU53").digest()` a saída: "`b'P.\xfd\xe9\xdez\xc0*\xf1\x0eC\x93\xc9L\xad\xaa'`"

O problema é que não conheço nada em php que me retorno isso, já fiz várias buscas e nada, lendo a documentação do php encontrei isso:

`echo openssl_digest("55M5033B556EUU53", "md5");` a saída: "`502efde9de7ac02af10e4393c94cadaa`".

Se eu fizer em python isso:

`hashlib.md5(b"55M5033B556EUU53").hexdigest()` a saída: "`502efde9de7ac02af10e4393c94cadaa`".

É a mesma do php, mas o problema é que eu preciso obrigatoriamente disso: "`P.\xfd\xe9\xdez\xc0*\xf1\x0eC\x93\xc9L\xad\xaa`" no php, alguém sabe me dizer como ou pelo menos me dá uma orientação do que devo pesquisar para encontra a solução.
Para eu termina o script em php só falta essa função, mas para eu tentar escrever essa função em php preciso do key nesse formato "`P.\xfd\xe9\xdez\xc0*\xf1\x0eC\x93\xc9L\xad\xaa`" pois se no python eu colocar isso "`502efde9de7ac02af10e4393c94cadaa`" na função da erro:

```
import hashlib
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from clint.textui import progress

    unpad = lambda d: d[:-d[-1]]

    def decrypt_progress(inf, outf, key, length):
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        assert length % 16 == 0
        chunks = length//4096+1
        for i in progress.bar(range(chunks)):
            block = inf.read(4096)
            if not block:
                break
            decblock = cipher.decrypt(block)
            if i == chunks - 1:
                outf.write(unpad(decblock))
            else:
                outf.write(decblock)


with open(inff, "rb") as inf:
    with open(outft, "wb") as outf:
        decrypt_progress(inf, outf, key, length)
```

inf é o arquivo criptografado
out local onde vai ser salvo o arquivo descriptografado
key = 55M5033B556EUU53
length tamanho do arquivo

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o que procura é converter o hex para binário. Assumindo que `hashlib.md5(b"55M5033B556EUU53").hexdigest()` tem o mesmo resultado do PHP.

---

Você pode usar o `hex2bin` (ou `pack`/`unpack`) ou defina o argumento "binary" no `hash` ou `openssl_digest` para `true`

---

Acredito que isso resolva:

```
hash("md5", "55M5033B556EUU53", true);

openssl_digest("55M5033B556EUU53", "md5", true);

md5("55M5033B556EUU53", true);

hex2bin(hash("md5", "55M5033B556EUU53"));
```

O `true` no final retornará em binário ao invés de hexadecimal.